# A jenkins-slave container image per module type or a single centralized one which can build anything?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-agent

I have multiple projects I need to build as part of the same CI flow - some are in java, some are nodejs, some are c++ etc.
We use Jenkins and slaves are supposed to run as docker containers.

My question is - should I create a Jenkins slave container image per module type, i.e a dedicated slave image which would be able to build java, and a dedicated container to build nodejs with node installed etc. or a single container which can build anything - jave, node, etc.

If I look at it from vm perspective, I would most likely use the same vm to build anything - which means a centralized build slave. But I don't like this dependency, or if tomorrow I need to update the java version and keep the old one I might create huge images with little differences between them.

Answer (score 1):

I personally would go down the route of a container-per-module-type because of the following:

1. I like to keep my containers as focussed as possible. They should do one thing and do it well e.g. build Java applications, build Node applications
2. Docker makes it incredibly easy to build Container images
3. It is incredibly easy to stop and start Containers

I'd probably create myself a separate project in Git that was structured something like this:

```
- /slaves
- /slaves/java
- /slaves/java/Dockerfile
- /slaves/node
- /slaves/node/Dockerfile
...
```

I have one Dockerfile that creates and builds the container image of the slave for the given "module type". I would make changes to this project via pull requests and each time a pull request is merged into master, push the resulting images up to DockerHub as the new version to be used as my Jenkins slaves.

I would have the above handled by another project running in my Jenkins instance that simply monitored my Git repository. When changes are made to the Git repository it just runs the build commands in order and then does a push of the new images to DockerHub:

```
docker build -f slaves/java/Dockerfile -t my-company/java-slave:$BUILD_NUMBER -t my-company/java-slave:latest
docker build -f slaves/node/Dockerfile -t my-company/node-slave:$BUILD_NUMBER -t my-company/node-slave:latest

docker push my-company/java-slave:$BUILD_NUMBER
docker push my-company/java-slave:latest
docker push my-company/node-slave:$BUILD_NUMBER
docker push my-company/node-slave:latest
```

You can then update your Jenkins configuration to the new image for the slaves when you're ready.

Comment: Thanks. Points 2 and 3 are valid for the centralized approach as well.
Your answer to some extent goes way beyond the scope of the actual question :) we do not use git nor dockerhub - I am just interested in what people think as the best strategy, and why.